# Extend $fn namespace in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

This seems simple but I cannot figure how to extend the $fn namespace.

**JS:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myorg.level1.level2.myFunction = function (usettings, params) {  
        return this.each(function () {
            //do work...etc
        });
    };
} (jQuery));

$("bla").myorg.level1.level2.myFunction(...);
```

How do I define the namespace chain so I can write functions like above?

The example I have given is very simple, the namespace isn't expected to be very deep however, I need to be able to extend and add functions...etc to my namespace tree at will.   I don't want to redefine the tree for each addtional function/level I add.

I haven't seen any good examples.  If I stay at the $fn level it's easy, but that doesn't make my code as clean and extensible as I need it.

If what I am asking for is not possible, what is the correct approach?

Comment: are level1 and level2 defined?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. What are you trying to do, and what is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: Why so deep? How many members do you have/expect in total?

Comment: Read about namespacing in the plugins authoring guide: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Namespacing

Comment: I've read just about everything on the internet including that article, none are clear on how to achieve my desired result.  I have updated the question.

Comment: You can't really "namespace" methods like this. When calling `$("bla").myorg.level1.level2.myFunctioN()`, the method's context will be the last name before it -- `level2` -- rather than the top-most jQuery collection.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: `$("bla").myorg.level1.level2.myFunction.call($("bla"))` :-P

Comment: @rickschott Perhaps, something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rW4jU/

Answer (score 1):

Epascarello hinted at this, but I'm guessing that the previous objects aren't defined.

```
console.log($.fn.myorg); // undefined

$.fn.myorg.level1 = function(){}; // TypeError: Cannot set property 'level1' of undefined
```

But if we define things first:

```
$.fn.myorg = $.fn.myorg || {}; // if this object doesn't exist, create an blank object
console.log($.fn.myorg); // object

$.fn.myorg.level1 = function(){};
console.log($.fn.myorg.level1); // function
```

Comment: while this will let you call `$("bla").myorg.level1()` you won't have the jquery context for the `level1` function, meaning `return this.each(function {})` will fail.